# ¿Cómo agrego un enlace href en PHP? ¿Cómo solicito informacion de la base de datos?

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos

Tengo un `<a href="">Pagar ahora</a>` en el `href` tiene que ir una url que está en la base de datos, (tabla "Products" y columna "pago")

Ahora me conecto a la base de datos, ¿como pido los datos ingresados en "Pago" y los coloco en el `href`?.

Comment: Busca información sobre mysqli y modifica la pregunta con el intento que hayas hecho para que podamos ayudarte a darle forma

Comment: No eres novato en SO. Ya deberías saber cómo preguntar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar, reproduzco tu dataset para montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
CREATE TABLE Products(
  pago varchar(255)
  );
INSERT INTO Products (pago) VALUES
  ('https://es.stackoverflow.com/');
```

Y, a continuación, el código en PHP que responde a tu pregunta:

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','stackoverflow');
$url=$conn->query("
    SELECT pago FROM Products;
")->fetch_row()[0];
?>
```

Y, el codigo final para llamar la accion:

`<a href="<?php $url?>">Pagar ahora</a>`

Déjame en los comentarios cualquier aclaración que necesites para completar la respuesta.

Comment: Hola David. No conviene responder cuando faltan datos en la pregunta. Por ejemplo pones un código basado en `mysqli`, pero no sabes si el OP usa esa API para consultar a la BD. Podría estar usando PDO, o las APIs de SQL Server o de PostgreSQL u otras... Es mejor esperar a que el OP aporte los datos que faltan. Además tu código es incompleto, pues muestra únicamente una fila de los resultados.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano, como pregunta cómo pedir los datos de forma tan genérica, entiendo que aún no lo tiene decidido, así que he optado por la solución más habitual. Del mismo modo, este código muestra la primera forma de pago que tenga registrada en la tabla, tampoco especifica que tenga más. Te propongo esperar a que lo defina el OP y, si lo he malinterpretado, rectifico o elimino la respuesta. Gracias por avisarme, la verdad es que ni contemplé las otras opciones